block nvme0n1: no uuid available providing old nguid - after disk cloning
On Rocky Linux 9.2 I made a copy of my full SSD with a software in order to replace the SSD, then I put just the new SSD in and booted from it, I seen a startup delay saying:
A start job is running for /dev/disk/by-uuid/AB24-1D3D (1min 27s / No limit)
Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/AB24-1D3D.
Dependency failed for /boot/efi
Dependency failed for Mark the need to relabel after reboot.

It continued OK to after I typed my password and system booted, but on df -h I only seen /boot mounted but not /boot/efi as it was before I cloned this disk.
I seen in /etc/fstab that it has a command to mount /boot/efi with that UUID AB24-1D3D
UUID=AB24-1D3D /boot/efi vfat umask=0077,shortname=winnt 0 2

I got the current UUID of nvme0n1 from ls -lha /dev/disk/by-uuid and replaced it in /etc/fstab.
Now on startup I don't get the long delay and error mentioned above and /boot/efi shows mounted OK when running df -h.
But now I get this one 1-2 times as as soon as it finishes booting to login prompt:
block nvme0n1: no uuid available providing old nguid

I noticed the above error is regarding UUID of nvme0n1 (main disk) and not a partition (e.g nvme0n1p1). I don't think I can set/change a UUID of main disk, rather than on a partition, no ? I tried in disks ubuntu program and gparted.
It all looks good thou, as I can tell all paths are mounted and services started.
But I don't know if this error is because:

I mixed up disk UUIDs somewhere?
OR because this new SSD fails to provide some ID to the kernel?

The new SSD is listed on motherboard compatibility list, but strangely I do not see it in BIOS under M.2 (shows empty) and previous SSD was showing there as brand/model. BIOS is updated and is very recent.
I found many answers saying this is a harmless warning, but I am still curious to see why it shows up or what it actually means.

How exactly was the cloning performed? (This is the most important bit of information; I would say 90% of the question contents can be removed as it's irrelevant, but this part must have been present from the very beginning.) A standard dd if=oldssd of=newssd would certainly clone it so new device contents, including UUIDs, will look indistinguishable from the old one.

I later cloned the same disk again but usig another software and this time it booted without errors / warnings and without the need to alter the UUID of partitions.
During the clonning I did pull both NVMEs in and out of the slots.
So not sure if the other clonning software helped or as @Kiyomizu answered, maybe the NVME needed to be reseated in the slot.
So if others have this problem, reseat NVME in slot first; Then if warnings persist, maybe try different methods of disk cloning.
Some more feedback on this would help.
Later edit: with any cloning software, after some hit and miss I think best practice is to NOT clone with both Linux drives in the computer, but rather only have one drive at a time in computer while cloning, make an image of it, replace the drive in computer then put the image on new drive. Because some disk cloning tools or the linux OS might come up with "fixes" if it sees duplicate UUIDs and alter your partition(s) UUIDs.

Glad you resolved your issue. In the future, I would strongly recommend changing only one thing when troubleshooting - that way it is easier to find out exactly what solved the problem. Technically, this is not possible, as one thing always changes without you wanting to or not - that is, the time - but it is still easier to narrow things down with 2 things as opposed to 3 (do not dismiss the time variable too easily - that's how sometimes the exact same configuration suddenly works where it didn't before, or the other way around).

"but usig another software" Can you share the names? It may help other users.

Can you share [software] the names? I wasn't sure recommending speciffic software is allowed here. Anyway, I usually tried cloning with Macrium Reflect, but sometimes booting complained about partition UUIDs, then I used MiniTool ShadowMaker which cloned 2 different drives nicely without any boot warnings.

The error "block nvme0n1: no uuid available providing old nguid" means the kernel can't retrieve the GUID (NGUID) for the new SSD, which is a detection issue.
Ensure the SSD is properly seated and connected.
Reset BIOS to default and reconfigure.
Try a different slot if available.
Check if BIOS "Secure Boot" or "Fast Boot" settings are interfering with disk detection.

So it could not be related to the software at all ? The UUID of partitions or so ? I later made another clone of original disk (using another software) and it booted without warnings and without the need to alter partitions UUID. But during this I did pull both NVME in and out from slots.

I will add my answer to my own question too and see what others might add to these answers over time.
